# Spring Integration. Missing Messages. Poll resulted in Message: GenericMessage

Tags: spring, spring-integration

Checking the output I find that some of the messages are being lost.
I enable DEBUG logging for *org.springframework.integration*. 
But I don't understand. Why I sending 4 message(4 files) to queue, but receive only 2, not 4.
What is it- Poll resulted in Message: GenericMessage?
How can i receive all message?

**integration.xml**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
       xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd
       ">
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="*"/>

    <int:poller id="defaultPoller"
            fixed-delay="1000" default="true" max-messages-per-poll="-1"/>

    <int:channel id="list">
        <int:queue capacity="100"/>
    </int:channel>

    <task:scheduled-tasks>
        <task:scheduled ref="get"
                        method="getList"
                        cron="5 * * * * *"/>
    </task:scheduled-tasks>

    <int:service-activator method="receive" ref="read" input-channel="list"/>

    <bean id="get" class="*.GetListFiles"/>

    <bean id="read" class="*.ReadOneChannel"/>
</beans>
```

**GetListFiles.class:**

```
      private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GetListFiles.class);

    private MessageChannel channel;

    public GetListFiles(@Qualifier("list") MessageChannel messageChannel) {
        this.channel = messageChannel;
    }

    @Value("${dir}")
    private String dir;

    public void getList() {
        try (Stream<Path> stream = Files.walk(Paths.get(dir))) {
            stream.filter(path -> Files.isRegularFile(path) && path.getFileName().toString().endsWith(".pdf"))
                    .forEach(path -> {
                        Message<Path> message = MessageBuilder.withPayload(path).build();
                        logger.info("Message send: {}", message);
                        boolean send = channel.send(message);
                    });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

**ReadOneChannel.class:**

```
       private static final Logger LOGGER =  LoggerFactory.getLogger(ReadOneChannel.class);
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("list")
    private QueueChannel queueChannel;

    public void receive() {
        Message message = queueChannel.receive();
       LOGGER.info("PAYLOAD: {}", message.getPayload());
    }
```

**Log:**

```
019-01-15 19:21:05 - Message send: GenericMessage [payload=/home/user/data/pdf/first/1.pdf, headers={id=af03c8be-5ace-c0f2-1a5f-7255202e76ba, timestamp=1547569265028}]
2019-01-15 19:21:05 - preSend on channel 'list', message: GenericMessage [payload=/home/user/data/pdf/first/1.pdf, headers={id=af03c8be-5ace-c0f2-1a5f-7255202e76ba, timestamp=1547569265028}]
2019-01-15 19:21:05 - postSend (sent=true) on channel 'list', message: GenericMessage [payload=/home/user/data/pdf/first/1.pdf, headers={id=af03c8be-5ace-c0f2-1a5f-7255202e76ba, timestamp=1547569265028}]
2019-01-15 19:21:05 - Message send: GenericMessage [payload=/home/user/data/pdf/second/2.pdf, headers={id=8cf90469-b677-9eb7-d944-388962d96fd7, timestamp=1547569265031}]
2019-01-15 19:21:05 - preSend on channel 'list', message: GenericMessage [payload=/home/user/data/pdf/second/2.pdf, headers={id=8cf90469-b677-9eb7-d944-388962d96fd7, timestamp=1547569265031}]
2019-01-15 19:21:05 - postSend (sent=true) on channel 'list', message: GenericMessage [payload=/home/user/data/pdf/second/2.pdf, headers={id=8cf90469-b677-9eb7-d944-388962d96fd7, timestamp=1547569265031}]
2019-01-15 19:21:05 - postReceive on channel 'list', message: GenericMessage [payload=/home/user/data/pdf/first/1.pdf, headers={id=af03c8be-5ace-c0f2-1a5f-7255202e76ba, timestamp=1547569265028}]
2019-01-15 19:21:05 - Poll resulted in Message: GenericMessage [payload=/home/user/data/pdf/first/1.pdf, headers={id=af03c8be-5ace-c0f2-1a5f-7255202e76ba, timestamp=1547569265028}]
2019-01-15 19:21:05 - ServiceActivator for [org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor@6a01928b] (org.springframework.integration.config.ServiceActivatorFactoryBean#0) received message: GenericMessage [payload=/home/user/data/pdf/first/1.pdf, headers={id=af03c8be-5ace-c0f2-1a5f-7255202e76ba, timestamp=1547569265028}]
2019-01-15 19:21:05 - Message send: GenericMessage [payload=/home/user/data/pdf/third/3.pdf, headers={id=a797d7c0-16b8-8b06-07ed-3bcb4f16ff9b, timestamp=1547569265032}]
2019-01-15 19:21:05 - preSend on channel 'list', message: GenericMessage [payload=/home/user/data/pdf/third/3.pdf, headers={id=a797d7c0-16b8-8b06-07ed-3bcb4f16ff9b, timestamp=1547569265032}]
2019-01-15 19:21:05 - postSend (sent=true) on channel 'list', message: GenericMessage [payload=/home/user/data/pdf/third/3.pdf, headers={id=a797d7c0-16b8-8b06-07ed-3bcb4f16ff9b, timestamp=1547569265032}]
2019-01-15 19:21:05 - Message send: GenericMessage [payload=/home/user/data/pdf/fourth/4.pdf, headers={id=7c5b1c90-1a9c-bdd3-5e33-1110f2d5933b, timestamp=1547569265033}]
2019-01-15 19:21:05 - preSend on channel 'list', message: GenericMessage [payload=/home/user/data/pdf/fourth/4.pdf, headers={id=7c5b1c90-1a9c-bdd3-5e33-1110f2d5933b, timestamp=1547569265033}]
2019-01-15 19:21:05 - postSend (sent=true) on channel 'list', message: GenericMessage [payload=/home/user/data/pdf/fourth/4.pdf, headers={id=7c5b1c90-1a9c-bdd3-5e33-1110f2d5933b, timestamp=1547569265033}]
2019-01-15 19:21:05 - postReceive on channel 'list', message: GenericMessage [payload=/home/user/data/pdf/second/2.pdf, headers={id=8cf90469-b677-9eb7-d944-388962d96fd7, timestamp=1547569265031}]
2019-01-15 19:21:05 - PAYLOAD: /home/user/data/pdf/second/2.pdf
2019-01-15 19:21:05 - handler 'ServiceActivator for [org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor@6a01928b] (org.springframework.integration.config.ServiceActivatorFactoryBean#0)' produced no reply for request Message: GenericMessage [payload=/home/user/data/pdf/first/1.pdf, headers={id=af03c8be-5ace-c0f2-1a5f-7255202e76ba, timestamp=1547569265028}]
2019-01-15 19:21:05 - postReceive on channel 'list', message: GenericMessage [payload=/home/user/data/pdf/third/3.pdf, headers={id=a797d7c0-16b8-8b06-07ed-3bcb4f16ff9b, timestamp=1547569265032}]
2019-01-15 19:21:05 - Poll resulted in Message: GenericMessage [payload=/home/user/data/pdf/third/3.pdf, headers={id=a797d7c0-16b8-8b06-07ed-3bcb4f16ff9b, timestamp=1547569265032}]
2019-01-15 19:21:05 - ServiceActivator for [org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor@6a01928b] (org.springframework.integration.config.ServiceActivatorFactoryBean#0) received message: GenericMessage [payload=/home/user/data/pdf/third/3.pdf, headers={id=a797d7c0-16b8-8b06-07ed-3bcb4f16ff9b, timestamp=1547569265032}]
2019-01-15 19:21:05 - postReceive on channel 'list', message: GenericMessage [payload=/home/user/data/pdf/fourth/4.pdf, headers={id=7c5b1c90-1a9c-bdd3-5e33-1110f2d5933b, timestamp=1547569265033}]
2019-01-15 19:21:05 - PAYLOAD: /home/user/data/pdf/fourth/4.pdf
2019-01-15 19:21:05 - handler 'ServiceActivator for [org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor@6a01928b] (org.springframework.integration.config.ServiceActivatorFactoryBean#0)' produced no reply for request Message: GenericMessage [payload=/home/user/data/pdf/third/3.pdf, headers={id=a797d7c0-16b8-8b06-07ed-3bcb4f16ff9b, timestamp=1547569265032}]
```

*Thank you for all the support.*

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 consumers on channel `list` - the service activator and your

`Message message = queueChannel.receive();`

Your `read` method should simply be

```
public void read(Message<?> message)
```

and the framework will invoke it with each message.

Comment: Thank you it works. I did not understand that I have 2 consumers on channel.

Comment: @boniq if it worked, it would be helpful to accept this answer :)